Extracting a Zip archive containing nested zip files using Kotlin
I'm working on an application that needs to extract a zip archive of json documents into a folder. The problem I'm encountering is that sometimes the archive contains nested zip files. My current code looks like this:
fun File.unzipServiceFile(toPath: String): List<File>
    {
        val retFiles = mutableListOf<File>()
        ZipFile(this).use { zipFile ->
            zipFile.entries().asSequence().forEach { zipEntry ->
                zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry).use { input ->
                    //if there are nested zip files, we need to extract them
                    if (zipEntry.name.endsWith(".zip")) {
                        //we need to go deeper
                    }
                    else if (zipEntry.name.endsWith(".json") && !zipEntry.isDirectory && !zipEntry.name.startsWith(".") && !zipEntry.name.startsWith(
                            "_"
                        )
                    ) {
                        val file = File("$toPath/${zipEntry.name}")
                        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, input.readBytes())
                        retFiles.add(file)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return retFiles
    }

I don't actually want to write the nested zip files to a folder since I would then have to clean them out of the directory. I simply want to extract the contents, or continue recursing if there are additional layers of nesting. Any idea how I could go about doing this?

You might want to edit the question and indicate what's wrong with the code you have so far. Does it not compile? Does it print errors when you run it? Does it compile and run just fine, but it doesn't do the job? What?

You can unzip a File by using a ZipFile instance, but you can also unzip the contents of an InputStream by using an instance of ZipInputStream:
zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry).use { input ->
    //if there are nested zip files, we need to extract them
    if (zipEntry.name.endsWith(".zip")) {
        ZipInputStream(input).use { zipStream ->
            val nestedZipEntry: ZipEntry = zipStream.nextEntry
            // ...
        }
    } else if ...
}

See here if you need additional help unzipping from a ZipInputStream:
How to read file from ZIP using InputStream?
